# When can I use the Whatever star?

Tags: raku, currying

Following [this post on perlgeek](http://perlgeek.de/blog-en/perl-5-to-6/28-currying.html), it gives an example of currying:

```
my &add_two := * + 2;
say add_two(5); # 7
```

Makes sense. But if I swap the `+` infix operator for the `min` infix operator:

```
my &min_two := * min 2;
say min_two(5); # Type check failed in binding; expected 'Callable' but got 'Int'
```

Even trying to call `+` via the `infix` syntax fails:

```
>> my &curry := &infix:<+>(2, *);
Method 'Int' not found for invocant of class 'Whatever'
```

Do I need to qualify the Whatever as a numeric value, and if so how? Or am I missing the point entirely?

[Edited with responses from newer rakudo; Version string for above: `perl6 version 2014.08 built on MoarVM version 2014.08`]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>Your Rakudo version is somewhat ancient. If you want to use a more recent cygwin version, you'll probably have to compile it yourself. If you're fine with the Windows version, you can [get a binary from rakudo.org](http://rakudo.org/downloads/star/).</del>

That said, the current version also does not transform `* min 2` into a lambda, but from a cursory test, seems to treat the `*` like `Inf`. My Perl6-fu is too weak to know if this is per spec, or a bug.

As a workaround, use

```
my &min_two := { $_ min 2 };
```

Note that `*` only auto-curries (or rather 'auto-primes' in Perl6-speak - see [S02](http://perlcabal.org/syn/S02.html#The_Whatever_Object)) with operators, not function calls, ie your 3rd example should be written as

```
my &curry := &infix:<+>.assuming(2);
```

This is because the meaning of the Whatever-`*` depends on context: it is supposed to [DWIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM).

In case of function calls, it gets passed as an argument to let the callee decide what it wants to do with it. Even operators are free to handle Whatever explicitly (eg `1..*`) - but if they don't, a Whatever operand transforms the operation into a 'primed' closure.

Comment: re whatever star and min: ["looks kinda buggy to me"](http://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2014-09-04#i_9298954).

Re auto priming: `m: sub foo ($a,$b) { say $a + $b }; my &bar = &foo.assuming(1); bar 3` works fine -- ie it works for arbitrary functions not just operators. (In fact operators are just functions with funny "long" names. eg the `+` infix operator is also known as `&infix:<+>`.)

Comment: @raiph: but `*` only auto-primes operator expressions: `&infix:<+>(2, *)` passes a `Whatever` as argument instead; explicitly using `assuming()` is not *auto* anything

Comment: Adding `{}` works for the operator, but the call via `infix:` parses but fails when called with a numeric argument with `Method 'Int' not found for invocant of class 'Whatever'. I don't really see why operators and functions would be treated differently for currying.

Comment: @PhilH: `perl6 -e 'my &curry := &infix:<+>.assuming(2); say curry(42);'` works fine here; function calls are treated differently because `*` is not the lambda-creation/auto-priming operator (or term, rather), but `Whatever`, which can have different meanings in different contexts; see [S02](http://perlcabal.org/syn/S02.html#The_Whatever_Object), which I already linked to in my answer

Comment: @Christoph My apologies. I thought "auto priming" was P6ish for partial function application. But that's just "priming". As you say, the auto bit involves the Whatever star and operators.

Comment: auto primed min not working has been filed as a bug: [RT #122708](http://rt.perl.org/rt3/Ticket/Display.html?id=122708)

Comment: **Dec-2015**: [RT #122708](http://rt.perl.org/rt3/Ticket/Display.html?id=122708) has been resolved. Both OP examples now work as expected: `perl6 -e'my &add_two := * + 2; say add_two(5); # 7'`  `perl6 -e 'my &min_two := * min 2; say min_two(5); #2'`